# Can we sort a terms aggregation on a string field other than the terms field?

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, aggregation

We have a terms aggregation with field as Field1.
We have to sort all the buckets using another field Field2 which is a string field.
There is a sub aggregation already in this aggregation.

**Is it possible to create another sub aggregation which would help sort the buckets in asc or desc order of field2?**

Using sort isn't helping in this case.

**Is it possible to sort the aggregation using Field2?**

I tried creating a new column by appending Field2 in front of Field1 and sorting using that column. But that had 2 drawbacks

1. Degrading the search capability
2. Uniqueness achieved by sorting using Field1 is lost. Meaning - Field2 can have more than 1 unique value for the
   same Field1 value. So the distinct count or number of buckets obtained is wrong when the new column is used.

**So, is there any way we can sort the documents of a certain index grouped as an aggregation based on a field other than the terms field?**

```
        "sources": {
            "terms": {
                "size": 150,
                "include": {
                    "partition": 0,
                    "num_partitions": 1
                },
                "field": "Field1.keyword",
                "order": {
                    "_key": "desc"
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "latest": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 1,
                        "_source": [
                            "Field3",
                            "Field2" 
                        ]               
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "distinct_count": {
            "cardinality": {
                "field": "Field1.keyword"
            }
        }
    }
```

Input:-

```
        "total": 868228,
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "deptindex",
                "_type": "metadata",
                "_id": "ID1",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "Name": "Ava",
                    "Dept": "D1",
                    "DateOfJoin": "2020-02-26T10:57:17"}
              },
              {
                "_index": "deptindex",
                "_type": "metadata",
                "_id": "ID2",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "Name": "Steph",
                    "Dept": "D2",
                    "DateOfJoin": "2020-02-24T10:57:17"}
              },
              {
                "_index": "deptindex",
                "_type": "metadata",
                "_id": "ID3",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "Name": "Carl",
                    "Dept": "D2",
                    "DateOfJoin": "2020-02-01T10:57:17"}
              },
{
                "_index": "deptindex",
                "_type": "metadata",
                "_id": "ID3",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "Name": "May",
                    "Dept": "D3",
                    "DateOfJoin": "2020-02-11T10:57:17"}
              },
...] }
```

Output :- All the top hits should be ordered in asc or desc order.

```
        "total": 25352,
        "max_score": 0.0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "sources": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "D2",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "latest": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": 2,
                            "max_score": 1.0,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "deptindex",
                                    "_type": "metadata",
                                    "_id": "ID2",
                                    "_score": 1.0,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "Name": "Steph"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                 {
                    "key": "D3",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "latest": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": 3,
                            "max_score": 1.0,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "deptindex",
                                    "_type": "metadata",
                                    "_id": "ID3",
                                    "_score": 1.0,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "Name": "May"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "D1",
                    "doc_count": 5,
                    "latest": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": 2,
                            "max_score": 1.0,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "deptindex",
                                    "_type": "metadata",
                                    "_id": "ID1",
                                    "_score": 1.0,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "Name": "Ava"
                                    }
                                },...
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: can you please share some sample index data and expected search result ?

Comment: If suppose Field1 is Department and Field2 is name
Dept: D.1 , D.2 , D.3
Names: Ava, Steph, Carl 
The key(_key for agg) will be Dept but the outputs should be sorted using Names.There can be many names in the same dept. That's why the distinct count changed when both these are appended in a new column.

Comment: it's not quite clear to me. Can you please share the data and expected search result in JSON format?

Comment: All the top hits should be sorted in an order based on the Name. I have edited the question for input and expected output